# Deploy app to Heroku with separate frontend/backend servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, heroku

I'm currently trying to deploy an app to a single Heroku dyno which does not use create-react-app but has an express server for webpack and a rails API backend.

I'm having issues getting express to proxy my requests to the API (but works fine locally), here is the error from Heroku logs:

```
2017-12-03T16:00:18.436271+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3005
2017-12-03T16:00:18.436308+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
2017-12-03T16:00:18.436309+00:00 app[web.1]:     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
2017-12-03T16:00:18.436311+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)
```

I made sure to use buildpacks for both node and rails as [described here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app).

Here is the relevant code:

**Procfile**

```
web: npm run start:prod
api: bundle exec rails server --port=3005 --environment=production -b 127.0.0.1
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:3005/",
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.10.2",
    "yarn": "0.24.5",
    "npm": "5.5.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=development node server",
    "start:prod": "yarn run build && NODE_ENV=production node server",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config ./webpack.prod.js --progress --colors --display-error-details"
  },
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const proxy = require('express-http-proxy');

const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')

const proxyHost = '127.0.0.1';
const proxyPort = '3005';

app.use('/api', proxy(`${proxyHost}:${proxyPort}`));

const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

let config

if (isProd) {
  config = require('./webpack.prod.js')
} else {
  config = require('./webpack.dev.js')
}

const publicPath = config.output.publicPath || '/';
const outputPath = config.output.path || path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'dist');

if (!isProd) {
  console.log('Development env detected: Initializing hot reloading')
  const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware')
  const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware')
  const compiler = webpack(config)

  app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler, {
    log: console.log,
    path: '/__webpack_hmr'
  }))

  app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
    entry: config.entry,
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
    stats: {
      colors: true
    }
  }))

  app.use('*', function (req, res, next) {
    const filename = path.join(compiler.outputPath, 'index.html')
    compiler.outputFileSystem.readFile(filename, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err)
      }
      res.set('content-type', 'text/html')
      res.send(result)
      res.end()
    })
  })

} else {
  app.use(publicPath, express.static(outputPath));
  app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.resolve(outputPath, 'index.html')));
}

app.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err.message)
  } else {
    console.log(`Server Started at port ${port}`);
  }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT FOR SOLUTION**

So I was able to get to a solution based on the accepted answer below, but thought I'd update the post to give the specifics.

As pointed out in the answer, it seems Heroku uses a different dyno per process in your Procfile, which was why the frontend/backend servers were originally unable to communicate with each other.

To circumvent this, I simply created a dummy procfile which used foreman to initialize the real procfile:

**Procfile (dummy used by Heroku)**

```
web: foreman start -f StartProcfile
```

**StartProcfile (the actual processes)**

```
web: npm run start:prod
api: bundle exec rails server --port=3005 --environment=production
```

It should be noted that in my case I ran into additional issues with exceeding the dyno memory cap AND taking longer than 60s to bind to the assigned heroku port. Turns out it was because I was including the build step as part of the `web` process, when I should have been using the `postinstall` hook in `package.json`.

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=development node server",
    "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production node server --optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=460 --gc_interval=100",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config ./webpack.prod.js --progress --colors --display-error-details",
    "postinstall": "npm run build"
  },
```

Comment: Hi Chris, I'm curious, what made you decide to use two frameworks instead of one? what not have it all on RoR or all on node? Do you mind sharing?

Comment: Well RoR is primarily a backend framework. It's great for static websites, but not designed for dynamic / single page applications like React is. I could've used node on the backend, but I am more comfortable with RoR so I decided to stick with that.

Comment: thanks. I love Ruby but I left RoR for other options just as 4.0 was coming out... I noticed I was only enjoying the ActiveRecord and migration parts, so I did away with the extra layers and opted for lighter options in Ruby land. Never looked back, but I still wonder from time to time why people stick to RoR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line in the `Procfile` ends up running in a separate dyno. If you need both processes to run on the same dyno (in this case `web`) then you need to either redefine `web` to call something like a shell script that launches the node server and then launches the rails server, or have the node boot process launch the rails server.

Full disclosure, I have never actually done what you are attempting. Binding the rails API server to port 3005 may not work even after making the changes outlined above. But, for sure, `127.0.0.1` in a `web` process will never be `127.0.0.1` in an `api` process since they will always run on different dynos.  Hopefully that info helps.

Comment: Could I just do something like `web: npm run start:prod && bundle exec rails server --port=3005 --environment=production -b 127.0.0.1`?

Comment: I have never tried it. But if that command runs locally in a unix terminal it should run on Heroku.

Comment: So did you manage to bind a port manually on Heroku? I'm having issues with Nuxt.js and Django, which is similar your situation, wondering if I can get away with using `&&` in one line without utilizing foreman.